# is `crontab -e` working on my MacOsX?

Tags: cron

I am reading a crontab guide. I am reading that crontab folder/path is

```
`/etc/crontab`
```

but on my MacOsX I cant find this path. I've read that with `crontab -e` I can edit my crontab. This command opens my `/private/tmp/` folder.[image]

After creating of crontab file or after updates of crontab.dfasdfasd find in this folder, when I exec the command `crontab -l` I always get same string:

```
`crontab: no crontab for sensorario`
```

So, the question is: where MacOsX look for its crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're stored in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs`, if you create a valid crontab entry, you will see a filename with your username in there.  You will need to use `sudo` to gain access to that directory.

`crontab -l` will also work once there is a valid crontab in place and will show you the contents of your crontab file.